# training set with only one label, missing the other

Tags: machine-learning, classification, speech-recognition, training-data

Hi I've been doing a machine learning project about predicting if a given (query, answer) pair is a good match (label the pair with 1 if it is a good match, 0 otherwise). But the problem is, in the training set, all the items are labelled with 1. So I got confused because I don't think the training set has strong discriminative power. To be more specific, now I could extract some features like:
1. textual similarity between query and answer
2. some attributes like the posting date, who created it, which aspect is it about etc.

Maybe I should try semi supervised learning (never studied it so have no idea if it will work)? But with such a training set I even cannot do validation....

Comment: Just for clarification, you have no negative examples on your dataset?

Comment: Yes. To be more specific, actually I've some unlabelled data giving me a confidence in telling if they are positive or negative. E.g. if the textual similarity between query and answer is very low, maybe I could say it's nearly impossible for them to be a match? Could I label it with NEGATIVE manually?

Comment: @Alessandro forgot to @ you..

Comment: Yes if you are confident you have some negative examples you should absolutely label them and include them in the training set otherwise your model will never learn how to distinguish positive/negative

Comment: @Alessandro The confidence is not that strong actually. So it may cause bias if I label them by hand.

Comment: I see, but with no negative label your model will never label anything zero because it will have never encountered it.

Comment: @Alessandro Got it, I will give it a try! Thx.

Comment: @Alessandro, that's not true: One-class SVM is quite capable of taking only positive data and drawing a kernel based on that set's cohesion.  Later data that's outside the training set's boundaries is labeled as 0 (negative).

Comment: This is a good question, although no detailed answer but still idea evoking

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *can* train a data set on only positive examples; 1-class SVM does this.  However, this presumes that anything "sufficiently outside" the original data set is negative data, with "sufficiently outside" affected mainly by gamma (allowed error rate) and k (degree of the kernel function).

A solution for your problem depends on the data you have.  You are quite correct that a model trains better when given representative negative examples.  The description you give strongly suggests that you *do* know there are insufficient matches.

Do you need a strict +/- scoring for the matches?  Most applications simply rank them: the match strength is the score.  This changes your problem from a classification to a prediction case.  If you do need a strict +/- partition (classification), then I suggest that you slightly alter your training set: include only obvious examples: throw out anything scored near your comfort threshold for declaring a match.

With these inputs only, train your model.  You'll have a clear "alley" between good and bad matches, and the model will "decide" which way to judge the in-between cases in testing and production.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Yes, I do need a strict +/- classification. I think your idea makes sense, which is quite similar to the Partially Supervised Classification in this paper: https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/S-EM/unlabelled.pdf